# What software is best for digitally commenting on drafts papers?

Tags: software

As I am asked more and more to review drafts of articles, I was wondering what software is best for giving comments digitally on draft papers (pdfs)? I know this is opinion-based, but I am curious what workflow is generally preferred/most popular.

Comment: You said "I know it's opinion-based", and I agree, so I'm voting to close. **however**, maybe you can think of a way of reframing/rephrasing so that the answers could be more objective? For example, you could come up with a list of features *you* would find useful and ask what tools/workflows have them. (This would have the advantage of getting answers that would be more useful to you.)

Comment: Me and people I know have often experienced compatibility problems when different software programs are used to write notes on the PDF. For example, you wrote your comments on a PDF program different from Adobe Reader, but your student opens the commented file on Adobe Reader, and there are comments missing, or no comments at all. The opposite situation is also common. Either use Acrobat to convert the PDF into Word, and write notes there or do everything in Adobe Reader making sure the student uses the same program to view the notes.

Comment: For pdf files, I started out using Skim for comments. When similar functionality became available in my standard pdf viewer, Preview on the Mac, I used that instead, until it lost a lot (but not all?!) of the notes in a couple of files. So now I'm back to Skim. (When collaborating on papers, my co-authors and I usually use LaTeX, and we insert annotations into the TeX file, using environments that show them in color in the resulting pdf file, different colors for different authors.)